# Finding which binary (library, driver, etc) caused an event log

Tags: windows-10, hypervisor

I found some events in the Windows Event Log, and I was wondering which binary caused them.

The event I am curious about is [Event ID 27 from Hyper-V](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd581940(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> Hyper-V launch failed; the Hyper-V boot loader was unable to allocate sufficient resources to perform the launch.

Any ideas on how to track which binary was in charge of emitting that event? I want to understand what resource is the one failing.

Comment: 1) If this were a linux program, I would run it with `strace` and search for libraries associated (your code likely load those dynamically) with the file descriptor that writes THIS PARTICULAR log message. There is something here related to `strace` equivalentes on windows (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864839/monitoring-certain-system-calls-done-by-a-process-in-windows). Sysinternals is probably the place to start.  2) If you have source, you could search for `HV_EVENTLOG_BAL_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` in a source file.

Comment: One of the problems is that I don't even know which binary is causing the event to be fired, and this happens early in boot, so I don't think strace would be of much help. I am thinking of remotely attaching WinDBG an check if I can see something from there

Comment: So you are doing process forensics on the windows boot-up process? Guess I didn't think deeply enough about the "boot loader" part of the message. Not an easy route, but you could emulate the system in Qemu (https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/gdb.html), halt it early in the boot with the monitor, attach GDB and do some forensics.  More complex would be using Panda (https://github.com/panda-re/panda).